# Website content moves when window is resized

Tags: html, css, web, resize, window

I have created a website and I have a problem since every time the window is resized the content in the website moves and does not remain ordered.

What can I do to fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Here is a code sample from my webite:

```
<section class="nav-panel nav-color" id="nav-panel-2">
    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/Starters/starters1.jpg">
        <img src="images/Starters/starters1.jpg" alt="Restaurant" width="600" height='auto'>
      </a>
        <div class="desc">Fried Ravioli</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/Starters/Starters2.jpg">
        <img src="images/Starters/starters2.jpg" alt="Restaurant" width="600" height='auto'>
      </a>
        <div class="desc">Cheese Bread</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/Starters/breadsticks.jpg">
        <img src="images/Starters/breadsticks.jpg" alt="Restaurant" width="600" height='auto'>
      </a>
        <div class="desc">Garlic Bread</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/Starters/mozzarellaSticks.jpg">
        <img src="images/Starters/mozzarellaSticks.jpg" alt="Restaurant" width="600" height='auto'>
      </a>
        <div class="desc">Mozzarella Sticks</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/Starters/wings.jpg">
        <img src="images/Starters/wings.jpg" alt="Restaurant" width="600" height='auto'>
      </a>
        <div class="desc">Chicken Wings</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem more specifically and add some code sample as well.

Comment: Hey try to read about responsive webdesign. Also change your website's div width to % percentage of actual width and set margin properly.

Comment: @TheDrot I have added a code sample now :) hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on your CSS. Edit the float, height, width, max-width, etc to create a responsive website. You need to use JavaScript and plug-ins like JQuery to further enhance the appeal of your website.

In general, this question won't get you any responses or answers. Join some tutorial or something on responsive web development.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin and padding attributes to center your elements. Create a wrapper div and then set margin: 0 auto; to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the position:absolute or fixed in the styles.
Example.
`#div{
position:absolute;
}`